# Getting NaN when calling function but not when clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've this method here. It works great and gives me the output when I activate it through a `button`.

However, just running the method `onBtnClick();`, it gives me `NaN` as a return value. When I call the method from my HTML file using `<input type="button" id="btnEN2LL" onclick="javascript:onBtnClick();" value="Convert"/>` the return value is correct.

```
onBtnClick();

function onBtnClick(){
    console.log(CnvEN2LL(21634.41000000015,33101.88000000082,0,','));
}
```

Is calling the method done wrongly?

Edit:

All the methods are declared below in the same file

```
function CnvEN2LL(easting,northing,latLngFormat,delimiter)
    {
    var e1,M1,u1,lat1,T1,C1,v1,p1,D,latRad,lngRad,e2,lat,lon;
    var LatDD,LatMM,LatSS,LonDD,LonMM,LonSS,LL;
    e2=SecondEccentricity();
    e1=calc_e1();
    M1=calc_M1(northing);
    u1=calc_u1(M1);
    lat1=calc_lat1(u1,e1);
    T1=calc_T1(lat1);
    C1=calc_c1(lat1);
    v1=calc_v1(lat1);
    p1=calc_p1(lat1);
    D=(easting-PROJ_FALSEEASTINGS)/(v1*PROJ_SCALEFACTOR);
    latRad=(D*D/2.0)-(5.0+3.0*T1+10.0*C1-4.0*C1*C1-9.0*Math.pow(e2,2))*(Math.pow(D,4)/24.0)+(61.0+90.0*T1+298.0*C1+45.0*T1*T1-252.0*Math.pow(e2,2)-3.0*C1*C1)*(Math.pow(D,6)/720.0);
    latRad=lat1-v1*Math.tan(lat1)*latRad/p1;
    lat=CnvRadToDeg(latRad);
    lngRad=(D-(1.0+2.0*T1+C1)*Math.pow(D,3)/6.0+(5.0-2.0*C1+28.0*T1-3.0*C1*C1+8.0*Math.pow(e2,2)+24.0*T1*T1)*Math.pow(D,5)/ 120.0) /Math.cos(lat1);
    lngRad=CnvDegToRad(PROJ_NATURALORIGINLONGITUDE)+lngRad;
    lon=CnvRadToDeg(lngRad);
    LatDD=Math.floor(lat);
    LatMM=Math.floor((lat-LatDD)*60);
    LatSS=(Math.round((((lat-LatDD)-(LatMM/60))*60*60)*100)/100);
    LatSS=roundNumber(LatSS,4);
    LonDD=Math.floor(lon);
    LonMM=Math.floor((lon-LonDD)*60);
    LonSS=(Math.round((((lon-LonDD)-(LonMM/60))*60*60)*100)/100);
    LonSS=roundNumber(LonSS,4);
    if(latLngFormat===0)
        {
        LL=lat+delimiter+lon
    }
    else if(latLngFormat==1)
        {
        LL=LatDD+':'+LatMM+':'+LatSS+delimiter+LonDD+':'+LonMM+':'+LonSS
    }
    return LL
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the function CnvEN2LL?

Comment: In the same file. The function is declared below

Comment: What does "*just running the method automatically*" actually mean?

Comment: By calling `onBtnClick();` it gives me NaN. When i call the function using `<input type="button" id="btnEN2LL" onclick="javascript:onBtnClick();" value="Convert"/>` in my HTML file, it works

Comment: It makes me wonder if the first time you're calling it, some of the constants this function is referring to are not yet assigned a value such as `PROJ_FALSEEASTINGS` or `PROJ_SCALEFACTOR` or others.

Comment: You use SecondEccentricity and a few constants like PROJ_FALSEEASTINGS. Where are they declared? And what does "running the method automatically" mean exactly? I guess te problem somethere in scope.

Comment: If you can reduce this problem to a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem, a quick breakpoint and stepping through the function will show us exactly where the issue is because you can watch the results of each individual line as you execute it line by line and see exactly where it goes wrong.  That's the methodical way to solve this kind of problem in your own code.  Set a breakpoint and step through the function.  If you haven't learned that yet, it's worth learning and probably takes about 10 minutes to get started in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. I didn't realise this. My variables are assigned values below. After assigning the values before calling the method, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment about this issue was the actual problem, I will post this as an answer.

It sounds like some of your constants such as `PROJ_FALSEEASTINGS` or `PROJ_SCALEFACTOR` or others may not yet have properly assigned values.  If they are assigned values after you call `onBtnClick();` the first time, then they won't yet be initialized the first time you run it, but when it is run later on an actual click event, they will have proper values.

This type of issue can definitely lead to `NaN` because you're trying to do math with `undefined` values.